# How to combine a query into a single CTE query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression

In code one below, there a query that finds the points of intersection in terms of longitude and latitude. And in code two, it is to show specific info like `type`, `properties` and `geometry`, etc.

What I want to achieve is to have the main query in code two contains information about the point of intersection "longitude and latitude" and the area as well. In other words, given the `geom` in code two, I would like to integrate code one into code two to have information about the points of intersection and area.

How can code one be integrated into code two?

**code1_to find the coordinates of intersection**:

```
query ="""SELECT ST_X(ST_Transform(point,4326)) as lon, ST_Y(ST_Transform(point,4326)) as lat, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(point,4326)),ST_Area(
                ST_Intersection(
                    ST_SetSRID(
                        ST_MakeEnvelope(ST_X(point),ST_Y(point),ST_X(point)+{width}, ST_Y(point)+{height}),25832),
                            ST_Transform(
                                    ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
                                        '{geometry}'),4326)
                                        ,25832)))
    FROM {table} 
    WHERE 
    st_intersects(
        ST_Transform(
            ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
               '{geometry}'),4326)
               ,25832),
                st_setsrid(ST_MakeEnvelope(st_x(point),st_y(point),st_x(point)+{width},st_y(point)+{height}),25832))""".format(table=config['PostgreDB']['table_name_test'], width=config['Grid']['cell_width'], height=config['Grid']['cell_height'],geometry=geometry)
```

**code2**:

```
query = """  WITH data AS (
        SELECT '{featuresCollection}'::json AS featuresCollection
        )
        SELECT gid,geom,type::text,properties::text,
        array_to_string(array_agg(x_4326||' '||y_4326 ORDER BY gid),',') AS g4326,
        array_to_string(array_agg(x_25832||' '||y_25832 ORDER BY gid),',') AS g25832             
        FROM (
        SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS gid,
        ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')) AS geom,
        feature->>'type' AS type,
        feature->>'properties' AS properties,
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))).geom) x_4326,       
        ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints((ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))).geom) y_4326,  
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)))).geom) x_25832,       
        ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)))).geom) y_25832       

        FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature FROM data) AS f) j
        GROUP BY gid,type::text,properties::text,geom
        ORDER BY gid;""".format(featuresCollection=featuresCollection)
```

**Sample data**:

```
[(3338490, 5668960, Decimal('1.02'), Decimal('52.08'), '0101000020E864000077D23C26C5A81441A9BAEC5A4F9E5541'), (3338490, 5668950, Decimal('0.77'), Decimal('52.13'), '0101000020E864000047A52726C5A81441D4552EDB4C9E5541'), (3338490, 5668940, Decimal('0.36'), Decimal('52.19'), '0101000020E864000005781226C5A8144109F16F5B4A9E5541')]
```

**Image of some data in the table**:

[image]

**Data in the featureCollection**:

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4530a6b206b68703a3036826d37228b)

Comment: could you also provide some sample data and show the exact expected result?

Comment: @JimJones i added a link to the data.it is the same data as in the previous one.please have a look. the data in the first select statement:SELECT '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properti

Comment: Can you also add the exact expected result? I'm confused about `code 1`. Where does the variable `point` come from? Where is the GeoJSON for `{geometry}`?

Comment: @JimJones for `point` it is a column in table "s_30m_test"
 for '{geometry}' it must be substituted with geom from "feature->>'geometry'"

Comment: Can you add some data sample from table `s_30m_test` and the exact expected result based on the given json document?

Comment: @JimJones i sent you a screen shot via yesterday's chat session..did you get it??please acknowledge

Comment: @JimJones morning, wow..thanks. however, when i execute the query, it returns lon, lat,ST_AsText(ST_Transform(point,4326)),
, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(point,4326)),...i would like to be able to return gid,geom,type, properties, x_4326,y_4326,x_25832,y_25832
would you please tell me how to the query can be modified to achieve that?

Comment: Did the last query work?

Comment: @JimJones every thing works but i get duplicate enrtris in" array_to_string(array_agg(x_4326||' '||y_4326 ORDER BY gid),',') AS g4326,
  array_to_string(array_agg(x_25832||' '||y_25832 ORDER BY gid),',') AS g25832" i added DISTINCT in front of the SELECT but did nothing. please advice

Answer (score 0):

Just place the query in `code 2` in the `FROM` clause and either join it with `code 1` or just match them in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
    query = """ 
        SELECT j.*,
            ST_X(ST_Transform(point,4326)) As lonOfIntersection, 
            ST_Y(ST_Transform(point,4326)) AS latOfIntersection, 
            ST_AsText(ST_Transform(point,4326)) pointOfIntersectionEPSG4326,
            ST_AsText(ST_Transform(point,25832)) pointOfIntersectionEPSG25832,
            ST_Area(
                ST_Intersection(
                ST_SetSRID(
                    ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    ST_X(point),
                    ST_Y(point),
                    ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                    ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                    25832),j.geometry
                )
            ) As areaOfCoverage
        FROM {table}
        JOIN (
            WITH data AS (
            SELECT '{featuresCollection}'::json AS featuresCollection
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT
            geometryID,geomType,geomProperties,
            array_to_string(array_agg(x_4326||' '||y_4326 ORDER BY geometryID),',') AS polygonsCoordinatesInEPSG4326,
            array_to_string(array_agg(x_25832||' '||y_25832 ORDER BY geometryID),',') AS polygonsCoordinatesInEPSG258,
            geometry
            FROM (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS geometryID,
                feature->>'type' AS geomType,
                feature->>'properties' AS geomProperties,
                ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))).geom) AS x_4326,       
                ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints((ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))).geom) AS y_4326,   
                ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)))).geom) AS x_25832,       
                ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)))).geom) AS y_25832,
                ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS geometry
 
            FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature 
                    FROM data) AS f) j
            GROUP BY geometryID,geometry,geomType,geomProperties) j ON   
            ST_Intersects(j.geometry,
                ST_SetSRID(
                    ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    ST_X(point),
                    ST_Y(point),
                    ST_X(point)+{width},
                    ST_Y(point)+{height}),25832));
""".format(table=config['PostgreDB']['table_name_test'], width=config['Grid']['cell_width'], height=config['Grid']['cell_height'],featuresCollection=featuresCollection)
```

Comment: Hi, would you like to answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738265/how-to-use-value-of-a-column-as-input-to-a-spatial-operation

Comment: Morning, i would test and acknowledge regarding your answer on Monday...have a nice weekend

Comment: hi, would you please answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558791/how-to-iterate-through-geojson-elements