# how to use value of a column as input to a spatial operation

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

given the code or the query posted below i would like to use the value of `XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer` snd `YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer`as input to the following statment:

```
ST_MakePoint(`XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer`,`YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer`)
```

please let me know how can i achieve that

**code**:

```
 SELECT 
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
            )))).geom) AS XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer,
            ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
            )))).geom) AS YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer,
```

**update**:

this is to further clarify my point ans make clearer. i have a main SELECT statement as shown in code1 . and i would like to add the WITH-clause the one shown in `with-clasue`section posted below to the end of the main `SELECT`
statment

when i just copy the with clasue and paste it i receive an error on the with clause it self. please let me know how can i fix it

**code_1**:

```
SELECT
....
....
....
ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
            )))).geom) AS XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZone,
ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakeEnvelope(
        ST_X(point),
        ST_Y(point),
        ST_X(point)+{width}, 
        ST_Y(point)+{height}),
        25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius})
    )))).geom) AS YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer,
    
    
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint((ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
            )))).geom))+5, (ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius})
            )))).geom))+5 ),25832) As midPoint,
            
            --WITH clause is to be added here.
```

**with claus**

```
WITH j AS (
        SELECT 1 AS X, 2 AS y -- your big query goes here
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
            )))).geom) AS XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZone,
            T_Y((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
            ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(point),
                ST_Y(point),
                ST_X(point)+{width}, 
                ST_Y(point)+{height}),
                25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius})
            )))).geom) AS YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer
            ),
            SELECT ST_MakePoint(XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer,YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer) As XYPointOfLowerLeftGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZoneInEPSG25832
```

**fiddle**:

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2928841af169e69c72faf282f04390b
```

Answer (score 0):

If they have to be in a single query, you simply need to use the output values of `ST_X` and `ST_Y` in the `ST_MakePoint` function. If the x and y values are in columns or are the result of an operation, you simply need to pass these values in the function:

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(column_x,column_y) FROM t;
```

Or in case they're inside geometries..

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(ST_X(a_geom),ST_Y(a_geom)) FROM t;
```

Using a `CTE` or a subquery (See comments). The principle is similar, but using a CTE you sort of create a temporary set and use it was as a table. The following example generates x and y values and name it `j`, then in the outer query you catch these values to create a point with another `SELECT`, but this time using `j`:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 1 AS X, 2 AS y -- your big query goes here
) 
SELECT ST_MakePoint(X,Y) FROM j;
```

Applying it to your query ..

Demo (subquery): [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=190e18c8f41deee45e53e2f5d8d846ab)

Demo (CTE): [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=de005ef98a584355dd835b23e8d7efb5)

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT 
    ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
        ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakeEnvelope(
            ST_X(point),
            ST_Y(point),
            ST_X(point)+{width}, 
            ST_Y(point)+{height}),
            25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
        )))).geom) AS XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer,
        ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
        ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakeEnvelope(
            ST_X(point),
            ST_Y(point),
            ST_X(point)+{width}, 
            ST_Y(point)+{height}),
            25832),ST_Buffer(j.geometry, {bufferRadius}) 
        )))).geom) AS YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer, 
    ....
)
SELECT ST_MakePoint(XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer,
                    YOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBuffer)
FROM j
```

A few thoughts on your query (without being able to see the big picture):

- `ST_AsText` definitely make no sense in you query. You can get rid of it.
- Note that the code you're using to extract the x and y coordinates are identical, and `ST_DumpPoints` already returns points. So, I believe your logic is flawed, since you're re-recreating the same point you previously split into separated values.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233185/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-jones-how-to-use-value-of-a-column-as-input-to-a-spa).